# What is the English verb for completing the missing exam?

Tags: word-request

My friend had an exam but he didn't come because he was sick. Then he needs to pass the exam even he wasn't there. What is the verb or phrase which describes what he needs to do?  ("making-up" the missing works here?)

In addition, in Europe, in some of the universities if you didn't come then you have to pay to the university on the missing class and then you have to go with the receipt to the professor of the missed class and you have to represent the topic that you missed and show him that you studied by yourself, and he asks question about the topic in order to ensure that this student controls in the topic. Is it called "making up" classes or it is something else?

Comment: There I was talking about classes rather than the exams. In addition the answer there didn't make me confident with the understanding the accurate cases to use the term "making up", particularly after my google research and checking for some forums about the using of this phrase.

Comment: My answer talked about exams too.

Comment: Okay, I see. Then can you please see my question here regarding the process with professor and tell me if it's proper use in this case as well because I'm not sure about it (since I'm not sure if you have this process in your countries). The last time I used this term "making-up" and the professor didn't understand me even she speaks English not bat at all. It made me non-confident.

Comment: In a scenario _without_ the "receipt" thing, _make up/makeup_ is fine. Now, the process with the receipt, I don't know if that has a name. As far as I know, that doesn't exist in the US, at least at a typical university. It might have a special name, but I don't know it. I imagine that if you handed the receipt to the professor and said "I need to/I would like to make up the exam", then the professor would understand. If you want, you can reword this post so that the focus is about this process so that it will not look like a duplicate. I think that should be ok.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Actually I don't know how to reword it in a way that it will not be considered as a duplicate. Anyway, regarding the professor, it absolutely can be that she just doesn't know this term since it's not in used around her, it doesn't say necessarily that I was mistaken, it is not common term for her maybe. She asked me what do I mean and I explained her and she didn't deny it or something like that.